# Why are they called bispinors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, spinors

In multiple sources I found the notion of **bispinor** as a label of one-electron wave functions in Dirac theory. In *Mathematical Aspects of Quantum Field Theory* page 107-108 it is stated that for every $s,t\in \frac 1 2 \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ there is a $(2s+1)(2t+1)$ dimensional complex irreducible representation of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ (and that any irreducible representation is one of these). As for $s,t=\frac 1 2$ this gives rise to a spin bundle (associated to a spin frame bundle) with fibre $F$, a complex vector space of dimension $4$ (i.e. $\mathbb C^4$), this means that a one-electron state is a section of this bundle, after which we make the assumption of this bundle being trivial so that such sections correspond to functions $\mathbb R^{1,3}\to \mathbb C^4$.

In my understanding these are the spinors, but **bispinors** are also such functions, why make a distinction then?

Comment: It's just another name for the Dirac spinor. The Dirac spinor of $\mathfrak{so(3,1)}$ has 4 complex components, and may be decomposed into a sum of two irreducible representations, the chiral and anti-chiral Weyl spinors, each of complex dimension 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the content in the book, they are spinors. The Dirac equation is invariant under Lorentz transformations, rotations and translations, or conveniently called, the Poincare group. The Lorentz group generates the Lorentz transformations and rotations in flat spacetime and has the group structure $SO(3,1)$. This is isomorphic to $SO(4)$ which is isomorphic to $SU(2) \times SU(2)$. Therefore any given state will transform similar to that under two angular momenta $(j,j')$ (angular momenta obey the $SU(2)$ algebra), which we can easily decompose to irreducible representations by their addition.

So for net angular momenta $1/2$, we have two separate irreducible representations, $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,0)$, from which we obtain two different spinors, which are called the Weyl spinors.  The Dirac spinor is a combination of both these spinors, and therefore commonly called a bispinor.

Comment: oh I see, so a half spin fermion does not correspond to the representation with $s,t=\frac 1 2$ but separately two representations with $s=\frac 1 2,t=0$ and $s=0,t=\frac 1 2$, then what is represented by $s,t=\frac 1 2$? one of the 3 representation of a system of spin 1? (is that a particle with spin one or multiple particles?

Comment: Yes, the $(\frac12, \frac12)$ field has spin 1. The sigma matrices let you move between the reps. A good summary of this theory is in the first chapters of Ideas And Methods of Supersymmetry by Buchbinder and Kuzenko.